# Using timestamps to find elapsed time between the end of one array and the start of another

Tags: objective-c, arrays

My iOS application involves a long mutable array of about 700 elements (let's call it *mainArray*), which comes from the average red values of user camera input. Because the elements in *mainArray* are taken from camera input, each element has a timestamp of when it was recorded.

If several consecutive elements of *mainArray* are within the vicinity of a certain value *x*, my algorithm will create a new (smaller) array, *smallArray*, and add all the elements of *mainArray* in the vicinity of *x* to *smallArray*. Due to the nature of the data I'm collecting, several of these smaller arrays will be created with gaps of time between them while the application is running.

I'm having trouble finding a way to measure the amount of time that has elapsed between the end of *smallArrayOne* and the start of the *smallArrayTwo*. How can I accomplish this?

*I should mention that when I say that some elements of mainArray will be added to smallArray, those elements will not be removed from mainArray. Rather, they'll be part of both mainArray and smallArray.*

*Because of this and the unpredictable nature of the data samples I'm using, it's impossible for me to know the mainArray equivalent of the last element in smallArrayOne and the first element in smallArrayTwo.*

Comment: What is preventing you from taking the the timestamp of the last element of `smallArrayOne` and subtracting it from the timestamp of the first element of `smallArrayTwo`? How are these arrays declared? You should show your code.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Edited to clear that up. These are NSMutableArrays, nothing unique about them. I'm not at home right now, but I should be there in about half an hour. I'll post my code then.

Comment: Can you post some code related to above scenario so we can get idea how can we help you from above problem?